# CSS grid layout fuid cell content size

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm new to css grids and I've made a dynamic grid layout for a simple selection of data via user input. The layout works as expected but I've got a problem achieving responsiveness for smartphone devices.

What I got is the following:

(Tablet view current)

[image: Tablet view current]

(Smartphone view current)

[image: Smartphone view current]

My desired result is to change the grid column layout for smartphone devices only to get it like this:

(Smartphone view desired)

[image: Smartphone view desired]

So what I probably need is a consistent way to change this:

```
.container--controls-buttons {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

To this:

```
.container--controls-buttons {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

for any kind of smartphone device. Since I am not able to tell which smartphones will be used, media queries according to device width aren't really an option for me. :/

You can check out my full code on the following codepen: https://codepen.io/manuelhrast/pen/RwbOwpX?editors=1100

Thanks in advance for any kind of help! :)

Comment: You can't target devices with mediaqueries, you will have to use media queries in combination with device width to achieve your goal.

Comment: But how can I ensure a an optimized view for every smartphone device using media query? :/

Comment: By using `@media (max-width: 400px)` for smartphones that are up to 400px wide. and then another one `@media (max-width: 600px)` for all devices that are up to 600px wide. And so on. That's how mediaqueries work and are designed to be used.

Comment: The only way to target smartphones only not by media queries would be to use some sort of library - we have used https://51degrees.com/ in the past but found this approach isn't as nice as responsive (and seemed to get penalised by google).  The point of media queries is that you target all devices of a certain width rather than just mobiles - it means your site will look nicer no matter what device it is on

Comment: I know that, but still, It kinda isn't consistent optimized for any kind of smartphone device if I don't use like many different media queries. :/

Comment: If you're primarily targeting mobile devices held in portrait mode, you could possibly get away with using the `orientation` media query alongside the `max-width` query https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation. Something like this `@media (max-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait)`

Comment: Yeah that is also an approach I already thought about. But since I don't have too many test devices I am not sure if it stays consistent for the most devices. I achieved the desired result using the following media query `@media screen and (orientation: portrait) and (max-width: 468px)` but can I really be sure it fits for most smartphones in portrait mode?

Comment: This is not really we can help you with here, I can just recommend you to look up the basics of responsive webdesign, then you will learn how to think responsive. Your approach with "I need to target smartphones" is not responsive at all and should be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update this media query will help. mostly all the smartphone will cover.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container--controls-buttons {
    grid-template-columns: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I guess I just try to use a media query like that and select it for portrait mode. Seems like theres no other / better way. :P The views are running in an mobile application which is forced to portrait for smartphones anyway.